# power play in T20 cricket

Tags: rules, cricket

‎In a T20 match, if a fielding side has only 10players(no substitutes also),then how many players can field outside the 30yrds in the first six overs.

Answer (score 6):

The T20 [international regulations](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542bbeee9ab7d-3%20_Standard_T20I_2014-15_Final_Oct_14.pdf) are quite clear about this:

Section 41.2.2.c says that "During the Powerplay overs only two fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area at the instant of delivery. "

Section 41.2.2.d says that "During the non Powerplay overs, no more than 5 fieldsmen shall be permitted outside the fielding restriction area referred to in clause 41.2.2 (b) above."

Comment: As an umpire tutor one of the things we stress to people around fielding regulations is that they always so no more than or no less than, and so regardless of the number of players in the team they apply