# Powerplay rule if there are 10 fielders on the field

Tags: rules, cricket

If there are 10 fielders on the field, how many fielders should be outside the 30-yard circle in **Powerplay** according to the rule?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: I'm not sure if it can be taken as duplicate of the question [*power play in T20 cricket*](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/power-play-in-t20-cricket/10381#10381) but the comment of *Ben Whyall* states:

> As an umpire tutor one of the things we stress to people around fielding regulations is that they always so no more than or no less than, and so regardless of the number of players in the team they apply.

Which means **Powerplay rule will still be same** depending upon the type of game you are playing, whether it be *ODI* or *T20* regardless of team size. In your case you have 10 players fielding at a time but that will not change Powerplay rule whatsoever.

From [Standard One Day International Match Playing Conditions – 2016-17](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/01/09/879a8d2a-c639-40bb-b416-6854c153f018/Standard-One-Day-International-Match-Playing-Conditions-2016-17.pdf) the rule states:

*41.2 Restrictions on the placement of fieldsmen*

```
41.2.1 At the instant of delivery, there may not be more than 5 fieldsmen on the leg side.  

41.2.3 (fielding restriction area is 30-yard circle)  
At the instant of delivery:  
a) Powerplay 1 - no more than two (2) fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area. In an innings of 50 overs, these are overs 1 to 10 inclusive.  
b) Powerplay 2 - no more than four (4) fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area. In an innings of 50 overs, these are overs 11 to 40 inclusive.  
c) Powerplay 3 - no more than five (5) fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area. In an innings of 50 overs, these are overs 41 to 50 inclusive.
```

If you are playing T20 cricket *law 41.2 Restrictions on the placement of fieldsmen* from [Standard Twenty20 International Match Playing Conditions – 2016-17](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/01/09/ce87a7ca-4aa7-44ad-8f5d-51bb20a52931/Standard-Twenty20-International-Match-Playing-Conditions-2016-17.pdf) will be applied.